# How to exclude certain fields from the _source field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following simple snippet:

```
PUT /lib36
{
  "mappings": {
    "_source": {"enabled": false}, 
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "description":{
        "type": "text"
      }
      
    }
  }
}

PUT /lib36/_doc/1
{
  "name":"abc",
  "description":"xyz"
}


POST /lib36/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  }
}
```

With `"_source": {"enabled": false},` the queried result doesn't include `_source` field.

I would to know how to write the query that the query result has the `_source` field ,but only contain name field, but not description field.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-source-filtering.html) of elasticsearch, but for that first you need to have `_source` enabled in your mapping.

You need to have below key-value in your search query JSON. below search will exclude all other fields apart from `name`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "abc"
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "name"
  ],
}
```

Comment: You should also state that the mapping needs to have `"_source": {"enabled": true}` instead of false (or remove the line entirely)

Comment: @Val, yes, i was gng to do that only :D